# installing numpy on a python 2.7 with system windows 8.1

Tags: python-2.7

I'm working on a code to run it in abaqus. I need in my code to use numpy module. I have python 2.7.11 on my computer. I have installed it on windows 8.1.
I have downloaded numpy-1.11.Zip already.
I look for an easy detailed guide for installing it on my python
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If you have pip installed on your system, execute

`pip install numpy`